# add to a empty dataframe in pandas a row and assign an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, append

I would like to add row to a dataframe and assign a index. I try to make myself clear with the following example:

This is my empty dataframe:

```
dfr = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])
```

after that I would like to add some row with an index that depends on a specific day of the week.

Here the code:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    
     dfr = dfr.append({'A':  i,'B': i+10}, index=[day])
    
     dayw = day.strftime('%A')
     if dayw == 'Monday':
        delta = pd.Timedelta("3 days")
     if dayw == 'Wensday':    
        delta = pd.Timedelta("4 days")
        
     day = day + delta
        
    
     print(day)
```

As you can notice, I am not able to deal with the index.
Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: `day` is not defined, so I can't run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfr = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])
from datetime import datetime as dt
for i in range(0,4):
     day = dt.now()
     dfr1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':  i,'B': i+10}, index=[day])
     dayw = day.strftime('%A')
     delta = '0 days'
     if dayw == 'Monday':
        delta = pd.Timedelta("3 days")
     if dayw == 'Wensday':    
        delta = pd.Timedelta("4 days")
     if dayw == 'Thursday':    
        delta = pd.Timedelta("5 days")
     day = day + delta
     dfr = dfr.append(dfr1)
```

Comment: it works. thanks. I have just put  delta = pd.Timedelta("0 days") and not delta = '0 days'

Comment: Would it be possible to substitute append with concat?